# Запуск *.exe, который находится на шаре

Tags: windows, cmd

Сценарий:

Допустим, на некоторой шаре лежит какой-то *.exe файл.

Из своей программы я запускаю командную строку, где запускаю данный *.exe с передачей аргументов.

*.exe делает какую-то работу и закрывается и так N-раз.

Вопрос в том:

При каждом обращении к *.exe я его буду "скачивать" в ОЗУ по новой или ОС его закеширует?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Любопытно, потестировал у себя в сети, вот что получил:

- При обычном запуске *.exe из сетевой папки его кеширования **не происходит**;
- Однако, если запущенная программа **уже есть в памяти** (висит как процесс) — файл **не гоняется по сети** при запуске второго экземпляра. Причём это работает, даже если запускать тот же файл, но с другими параметрами.

Как вывод — очевидный костыль: запустить одну копию программы, чтобы она висела в памяти, и последующие копии не гонялись по сети. При необходимости воспользоваться приостановкой процесса или даже запуском под отладчиком, если программа имеет тенденцию самостоятельно закрываться слишком быстро.

А теперь перейдём к нормальному решению. В Windows встроен механизм **автономных файлов**, позволяющий работать с сетевыми папками без доступа к сети (т.е. механизм кеширования). Настраиваться он может с обеих сторон.

**1)** Владелец сетевой папки может:

- Разрешить кеширование (по умолчанию);
- Полностью запретить кеширование;
- Сделать его принудительным для всех открываемых сетевым пользователем файлов.

Настраивается это так: *Компьютер → Управление → Общие папки → Общие ресурсы → Свойства → Настройка автономного режима*

**2)** Со стороны пользователя можно:

- В проводнике выбрать нужный файл и в контекстном меню поставить галочку на пункте «Всегда доступно автономно»

Централизованное управление всеми файлами, для которых настроен автономный доступ, есть в *Панели Управления*, в разделе *Центр Синхронизации → Автономные файлы*.

Comment: А что ты использовал, что бы увидеть, что прога повторно не качается?

Comment: Просто мониторил трафик. Даже по его объёмам было сразу видно, пролезает туда программа или нет

Comment: `запуском под отладчиком` – я почему-то думал, что отладчик врезает дополнительный отладочный код в приложение, так что это не будет копия той же самой программы.

Comment: @NickVolynkin , что-то действительно мешает, но по-моему, дело не в дополнительном коде: 
1) Из-под Cheat Engine создаю процесс под отладчиком (трафик заметно меньше, чем при полноценном запуске) и оставляю висеть на первой инструкции. Результат — последующие экземпляры идут по сети.
2) В отладчике нажимаю Run (снова трафик, на этот раз как от полноценного запуска), затем Break. Результат — костыль на кеширование снова работает.
Итого, странное поведение: отладчик что, докачивает исполняемый файл по мере необходимости? Тут уже объёмами трафика не обойтись, пойду его расшифровывать.

Answer (score 0):

Сам по себе SMB не может чтото закешировать(может кроме метаданных).
Чтобы происходило кеширование файлов, нужно настроить чтото вроде [BranchCache](https://www.atraining.ru/branchcache-windows-10-server-2016/)